# Get Cookie made with javascript in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies, pantheon

I am using JS Cookie.

```
Cookies.set('cookie1','cookieValue');
```

Yet in PHP when I try to get the cookie I get NULL

```
var_dump($_COOKIE['cookie1']);
```

I can see the cookie in the console and if I run

```
var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

I can see all other cookies but not this one (cookie1)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the domain on the cookie1?  Does it match the domain for the php file location?

Comment: I did not set it. I was under the impression that I did not need to

Comment: Try setting it to match the domain the php file exists on.  The browser only adds cookies to the HTTP request that match the domain, as far as i am aware

Comment: Where you want to verify the cookie is there is in the request headers. Look for all 'Cookie: ...' lines. Are you sending the request to the same domain where the cookie is set?

Comment: @Taplar I set the domain of the cookie but still getting NULL on the php side

Comment: Interestingly enough in PHP when I do this: setcookie("jason","test");
 echo 'COOKIE - ' . $_COOKIE['jason']; it comes up empty but I can see it in the console

Comment: Still not able to get the cookies. anyone else with any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. We are using Pantheon and they use Varnish Cache. Varnish was set to only cache certain cookies. We had to add SESS to the beginning of the cookie name and change it from camelCase to snakecase. I am posting this as an answer in case anyone else ever has this problem.

Answer (score 0):

js :

```
var tempo = 1;   //   data in cookie
document.cookie='cookie='+tempo;
```

php :

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["cookie"])) 
  echo $_COOKIE["cookie"]; 
else 
  echo "Cookie Not Set";
```

Comment: Another clue to this mystery... I can read the cookie with javascript but not with php however I am able to read other cookies via php. I am also in wordpress